# How do I dynamically build access to hashes using freemarker?

Tags: java, templates, freemarker

I have the following freemarker template if statement:

```
<#if errorMap.[pageText.PART_NUMBER"_"i]??>
    <#assign textClass="error">
</#if>
```

I am looking to check if that particular variable exists in the errorMap hashmap, but am getting the following error:

Exception created : freemarker.core.ParseException: Encountered "[" at line 37, column 73

I can't seem to figure out how to build the call to retrieve that from the hashmap. I have also tried surrounding the variables inside the [] with ${}, but that didn't work either. Is it even possible to build the call I am trying to make?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes that fixed it. Stupid stupid mistake that I realized 2 minutes after I posted the question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the `.` after `errorMap`?